# Activate the site collection publishing feature gives error: The content type "Page Layout" at "/teams/T200001/_catalogs/masterpage" is read only

Tags: feature-activation

I have a sp 2010 site collection. When I try to activate the site collection "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature I got this error:

> The content type "Page Layout" at
>   "/teams/T200001/_catalogs/masterpage" is read only.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Go to Site Content Types, then, go to the Document Content Types section
> 2. Click Document in that section
> 3. Click Advanced on the Site Content Types for that content type
> 4. In the Read Only section of that page click YES
> 5. Click OK

Source: Geoff Evelyn's answer here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc53d0ff-b7b4-4cc3-b3e9-87af23f8ba8e/powershell-command-to-set-the-masterpage-page-layout-content-type-readonly-to-no?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Or

> ```
> $w = get-web http://myweb
> $list = $w.Lists["_catalogs/masterpage"]
> foreach ($item in $list)
>
> {$item.ReadOnly = $false
> $item.Update()}
>
> $w.Dispose()
> ```

Source: Chilly Moon's answer here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc53d0ff-b7b4-4cc3-b3e9-87af23f8ba8e/powershell-command-to-set-the-masterpage-page-layout-content-type-readonly-to-no?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: This appears to be a copy-paste from Geoff Evelyn's answer here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc53d0ff-b7b4-4cc3-b3e9-87af23f8ba8e/powershell-command-to-set-the-masterpage-page-layout-content-type-readonly-to-no?forum=sharepointadminprevious . Please make it very clear that you are "borrowing" information by adding a source